# Javascript to select first option of select list

Tags: select, reset

I need to create a reset button which on click will set all select lists in a form to index 0. I have tried this code for function, but it gives a syntax error on myForm.length;

```
<script type="text/javascript">function ResetForm(form) {     
var myForm = document.forms[form];   
  for( var i=0; i < myForm.length; i++ ){                                   
myForm.select[i].selectedIndex =0;     }  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no such property as `someForm.select`, try this instead:

```
selectTags = myForm.getElementsByTagName("select");

for(var i = 0; i < selectTags.length; i++) {
  selectTags[i].selectedIndex =0;
}
```

Comment: selectElement.selectedIndex = 0;

Answer (score 17):

A quick note to answer from Ron Royston
(I've only tried this on Chrome 74.0)

Setting `mySelect.selectedIndex = 0;` or `$('#mySelect').prop("selectedIndex", 0);` won't work if the option if it's disabled.

Hope this saves someone some time and frustration!

Answer (score 9):

You simply need to set the `.selectedIndex` property, as in `mySelect.selectedIndex = 0;`.  Try out the example below.

```js
var doc = document;
var myCheckbox = doc.getElementById('my-checkbox');
var mySelect = doc.getElementById('my-select');

myCheckbox.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if (this.checked){
    mySelect.disabled = false;     
  } else {
    mySelect.selectedIndex = 0;
    mySelect.disabled = true;     
  }
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox" value=""> Enable Dropdown</label><br>

<select id="my-select" disabled>
  <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">Select credential</option>
  <option value="apples">apples</option>
  <option value="oranges">oranges</option>
  <option value="bananas">bananas</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will set every selection directly after changing to the first option:

```
    <select onchange="your_selection_func(); this.selectedIndex=0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find jquery useful here. This SHOULD do the trick...

```
$(function()
{
    $('.resetButton').click(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('form').find('select').each(function()
        {
            $(this)[0].selectedIndex=0;
        });
    });
});
```

`<input type="reset" class="resetButton" />`

Answer (score 0):

I found some hack:

```
<select onchange="doSomething()">
  <option value="a" selected disabled hidden>a</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="…">…</option>
</select>
```

combination of `selected disabled hidden` causes that (visualy) first option responds with `change` event (even with same `value`!).

Working with IE, Edge, Opera, Chrome, but **not** working in FF :(

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is kinda old, but wanted to improve on teh1's answer. There's no reason to create a jQuery object from 'this' when you're just going to grab the DOM element back from it:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('select').each(function() {
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```